# Google Sheets: Removing first 6 lines from cell (data has line breaks and repeated text)

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

[Image of Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLrC5.png)

As you can see, we have some cells filled with data but there is some repeated data in the first 6 lines of every cell. I need those first 6 lines removed in every cell. Is there a way to do this easily enough?

I'm not an advanced user so some of the fixes I've found are a bit confusing for me. I've tried removing by # of characters but that isn't a consistent #. I really just want to say "Remove the first 6 lines" instead of "remove however many characters." I can't find that specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

Click on extensions at the top, then apps script. Paste in this code:

```
function removeFirst6Lines() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var values = range.getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
        if (typeof values[i][j] === "string") {
            var lines = values[i][j].split("\n");
            if (lines.length > 6) {
                var removedPart = lines.slice(0, 6).join("\n");
                var remainingText = lines.slice(6).join("\n");
                if (remainingText.startsWith(removedPart)) {
                    values[i][j] = remainingText.trim();
                } else {
                    // If remaining text doesn't start with the removed part, keep the original value
                    values[i][j] = values[i][j].trim();
                }
            } else {
                // If the number of lines is 6 or fewer, keep the original value
                values[i][j] = values[i][j].trim();
            }
        }
    }
}

range.setValues(values);
}
```

Then hit run and it will remove the first 6 lines of text from each cell. Every time you want to use it, navigate back to the apps script page and hit run.

Comment: I think a test should be added to check if the remaining text starts with the same text as the removed part. (Because that part is repeated). when it is not repeated, I do think you should not remove the first 6 lines? (I know it's not mentioned in the question)

Answer (score 1):

If the text is in A1, try this formula in B1:

`=index(split(substitute(A1,char(10),"|",6),"|"),0,2)`

Here is how it works:

1. use `substitute()` to replace the 6th occurrence of new-line i.e. Char(10) by pipe i.e. "|"
2. use `split()` to split the result by pipe
3. use `index()` to get the 2nd column in the array of value

Comment: This is giving an error when you have less than 6 lines (https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9WsA.png )

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.*?\n){6}",)
```

#### Update

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^(.*?(\n|$)){1,6}",)
```

Comment: A link to the [DOCS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en) might be helpful.  This is replacing the piece that is matched by the regular expression `(.*?\n){6}`, with nothing. (see:  [attempt with 8 lines](https://regex101.com/r/kVVmFA/1) which selects the first 6 lines, and [attempt with 3 lines](https://regex101.com/r/QffLxm/1), which is giving no match so nothing is deleted.

Comment: This did indeed work! Thank you!